# What's wrong with document.write? What's a viable alternative?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, document.write

I've read around that `document.write()` is a bad idea to incorporate into my webpage.  However, [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com), and the [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org) both use this function in tutorials.

What is wrong with `document.write()`, and what are some alternatives to using it?

*NOTE:  I've read similar questions here on SO, but I'd like a detailed answer that draws from official sources.*